How to default start Run/Debug configuration in DEBUG mode on InteliJ
I have a compound 'Run/Debug Configuration' with npm and springboot,
I would like to default start my springboot 'Run/Debug Configuration' in debug mode
Where In 'springboot Run/Debug Configuration' can add this option for automatically start in debug?

Thank for your help
